# ¿Cómo puedo enviar un archivo mediante Ajax con Laravel?

Tags: php, html, jquery, laravel

Este es mi código **jquery**, donde estoy enviando todos los datos que tengo pero no me envía el archivo que subo en el input file.

```
 $('#save-form').click(function () {
            $.easyAjax({
                url: '{{route('admin.apply_job.update', [$userDetail->id])}}',
                container: '#updatePretemporal',
                type: "GET",
                redirect: true,
                data: $('#updatePretemporal').serialize()
            })
        });
```

Este es mi formulario resumido, el número telefónico lo recibo pero no el archivo.

```
{!! Form::open(['id'=>'updatePretemporal','class'=>'ajax-form','method'=>'PUT']) !!}
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="form-group">                                                   
            <label>@lang('app.mobile')</label>
            <input type="tel" name="mobile" id="mobile" 
                   value="{{$userDetail->mobile }}" class="form-                            control" autocomplete="nope">
         </div>
       </div>

        <div class="col-md-4">
         <input type="file" name="id" id="id">
        </div>
      </div>
 {!! Form::close() !!}
```

Esto es mi controlador donde recibo los datos que envía el **ajax** e intento recibirlo de esa manera como es supuesto que se reciben en **laravel** pero no recibo nada.

```
public function update(CommonRequest $request, $id)
            {
                $file = $request->file('id')->store('public');
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hola Jhon que tal como estas?

mira, yo he tenido ese problema, pero lo mejor es usar dropzone.js es una Biblioteca para subir imágenes. bueno el código es así según mi experiencia

file.blade.php

```
@extends('template.main')

@section('styles')
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://rawgit.com/enyo/dropzone/master/dist/dropzone.css">
@endsection
@section('content')
  <form action="/mi-ruta/uploadImage" class="dropzone" id="Dropzone" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    @csrf


    </form>
@endsection
@section('scripts')
   <script src="{{asset('assets/js/lib/dropzone/dropzone.js') }}"></script>

@endsection
```

ok. una vez hecho esto, te vas al controlador donde este asociada la ruta, creas el método uploadImage o como ud desee llamarlo

ImageControlle.php

```
public function uploadImage(Request $request){

    $image=$request->file('file');
    $new_name = rand() . '.' . $image->getClientOriginalExtension();
    $image->move(public_path('storage'), $new_name);



    $SupportImage = new SupportImage;
    $SupportImage->image="/storage/".$new_name;
    $SupportImage->support_id=$request['support_id'];
    $SupportImage->user_id=\Auth::id();



    $SupportImage->save();
}
```

Dropzone hace esto automaticamente y se sube de manera rapida una o n imagenes, archivos, lo que sea realmente, con ajax.

Cualquier cosa, escribeme y te ayudo.

Espero que te sirva

en la pagina de la biblioteca te puede ayudar o dar una vision de como funciona https://www.dropzonejs.com/#usage

Comment: Hola puntozap,Tu respuesta me funciono correctamente el único inconveniente que tengo es al eliminar la imagen que ya subí, no se si sepas el como hacerlo

Comment: Hola Jhon. no lo he probado, pero vi que un amigo le funciono, entonces, lee esta parte de la documentacion de laravel entonces hacer el borrado logico en la base de datos lo tienes resuelto, pero, el borrado fisico en el archivo, lo haces asi https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/filesystem#deleting-files

Answer (score 1):

El método de envío serialize solo sirve para enviar cadenas de texto/string, pero no para enviar archivos, en ese caso debe utilizar **formData** ya que permite enviar datos tipo **BLOB, FILE y STRING,** prueba el siguiente código:

```
$('#save-form').click(function () {
        var data = new FormData('#updatePretemporal');
        $.easyAjax({
          url: '{{route('admin.apply_job.update', [$userDetail->id])}}',
          container: '#updatePretemporal',
          type: "GET",
          redirect: true,
          cache: false,
          contentType: false,
          processData: false,
          data: data
    })
```

De igual modo, revisa la consola del navegador y verifica los errores que genere la petición.